# Server Error (500) al intentar enviar email, con Django

Tags: django, smtp

Tengo un error en mi archivo de setting en django. Cuando quiero mandar un mail desde la pg, me da el error. Este es mi archivo de configuración.
He configurado postfix y no sé qué puede estar ocurriendo.

```
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
    EMAIL_PORT = 25
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Gus <gusunavarro@gmail.com>'
```

Comment: No olvides enmascarar tu email real, es carnada fácil para los bots :)

Comment: Pon el log completo de que error te esta dando, comparte el código que esta produciendo el error, de esta manera esta imposible saber que pasa.